# Why does Print Composer take ages "Creating icon for file ..."?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Every time I open a Print Composer, a box comes up, and text flashes by saying, "Creating icon for file [various random image files that I have on my computer]". It then pauses, and does it again, and does this 4 or 5 times before really opening it and letting me work.

Any idea why in the world it is doing this?

The image files I can see have nothing to do w/ anything I've ever done on QGIS.

Windows 7; QGIS 1.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is QGIS creating a icon for all the svg images. Try the latest dev version of QGIS to see if it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Are you thinking that these images are .svg's? They're jpg's, png's, etc..

Are there risks in using the dev version, for a person like me who struggles w/ even making the basics work, and who does not want to deal with glitches that may exist in a version that has not had the bugs worked out yet? If so, I can live with this issue until the new version is fully ready.

Thanks again for your thoughts.

Comment: You can run both 1.8 and dev side by side if you use the OSGeo4W install.  However if you don't like the idea of things changing day to day or things semi then I would stick to 1.8 for now.